# Projectile one dimensional optimization problem

Tags: calculus

Suppose a projectile is thrown with initial velocity $v$ aimed at some angle $\alpha$ wrt ground to hit a target of some height $h$. Given the horizontal distance satisfies (g = 10 m/s)

$$ \left( \frac{ g }{ 2 v^2 \cos^2 \alpha } \right) x^2 - (\tan \alpha ) x + h = 0 $$

My question is. This equation is supposed to give the horizontal distance, but it has two roots. I know that $x > 0$ and we can disregard the negative root. But, how about if for some $v, \alpha ,h$ we obtain two roots $x_1$ and $x_2$ which are both positive. Which one is supposed to be the horizontal distance we want?

Comment: If $\tan \alpha >0$ and $h>0$ there will in fact be 2 positive solutions for $x.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your projectile will reach height $h$ twice during its flight (assuming $h>0$), once on its way up and once on its way down.

If there are no other details then both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are valid answers to the question 'When will the projectile reach height $h$?'

Comment: Contradicting Aristotle, who wrote that a thrown projectile travels in a straight line until at some point it drops straight to the ground. ("You can't make this stuff up.")

Answer (score 1):

If you get two solutions both will be correct.  One will be very fast, traveling on almost a straight line to the target.  The other will be a high arc also hitting the target.